# Share Cursor Position on an element using jquery & php

Tags: php, jquery, html, cursor

Is it possible to share across the cursor position in an element say with the `class="board"` so that others can see it as a translucent circle or something?

1. Is it possible to get the cursor position with jquery?
2. Is it possible to pass them over to another user and replicate it there with an image?
3. If its possible, what will be the best method to do so?

Comment: When you say "cursor position" do you mean mouse or text cursor?  Also, I'm not sure what you mean by #2.  You might also want to show us what you've tried already so it looks like you've tried (maybe show a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/))

Comment: This a something like whiteboard... so the other people in the same page will see where the cursor of the main person is pointed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the mouse position using mousemove events:

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
    console.log(e.pageX +', '+ e.pageY);
});
```

If you want to transfer the information to another user, just send the coordinates via an XMLHttpRequest to your server and then bounce that data back to that user. This will give you a bit of lag, but that's to be expected.

If I correctly understand what you mean by "replicate it there with an image", just used a fixed-positioned cursor image (set with Javascript using the coordinates you receive) to simulate both cursors being there at once.